# Running dmesg on Docker results in "dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Permission denied"

Tags: docker, centos7, dmesg

In order to debug why [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/754097/running-systemd-on-docker-results-in-failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation?noredirect=1#comment947017_754097) occurs the following command is run on a container:

```
docker run -it <dockerImageName> dmesg
```

results in:

```
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Permission denied
```

**Attempts**

1. Running `docker run -it <dockerImageName> sudo dmesg` returns the same issue

Comment: You aren't allowed to do that in a container. What's the purpose of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) mentioned, containers are meant to run only single atomic service. As a matter of fact, one should understand that containers are not virtual machines but a single process by itself on your localhost.

Nevertheless, I got to know that, its a bit more harder to get SystemD working inside a container from [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7459)

> I was able to get SystemD working inside an image built FROM
>   centos:centos7 with:
>
> docker run --privileged  -ti -e "container=docker"  -v
>   /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup  trinitronx/ansible-base:stable-centos7 
>   /usr/sbin/init
>
> For some undocumented reason the variable
>   container=docker is apparently required. /sys/fs/cgroup is also
>   required, as SystemD needs cgroups to work properly according to
>   RedHat Bug 1033604.

After doing this, try to login to the container using `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash` and then you could execute your `systemctl` commands.

Comment: Would this be safe enough to run in production? I will try to run the binary instead of using systemd.

Comment: No, I suppose as its using "privileged" and also mouting /sys directories into the container. I thought this was just for debugging temporarily. Services should not be started with `systemctl` after containers are up. It should be part of CMD. e.g. [This is how httpd is started](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/1f1f7d39d5fe5aebeedea6872786b4e3ce0ebcc9/2.4/Dockerfile). However, have you every thought, how do you automate the starting of those processes after the container has started?

Comment: So the solution is to use `--privileged` :) . Helped me viewing `dmesg` and mounting using CIFS! Thanks.

Comment: the `--privileged` should be highlighted IMO, this helped _a lot_ while testing things locally as I have no plan to run like this in production.

Comment: If you use docker-compose and run into this problem, add the capability `CAP_SYSLOG` under the array `cap_add`. https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37929

Comment: Instead of `--priviledged` you can also use `--cap-add CAP_SYSLOG` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities